# Git - My branch is based off of an unwanted commit by mistake, how to fix

Tags: git, rebase

So I forked an open source project, and sent in a bugfix last week that was not pulled into their master. I created that fix on a separate branch, rebased it on top of upstream's master, and issued a pull request from that branch. However, I then began work on a new issue, but mistakenly created this new issue's branch off of the branch I created for the original bugfix.

So now I have that commit directly below mine in the branch I'd like to push up and issue a pull request to. I fetched and merged all updates to upstream/master into my master branch, and I'd like to rebase this new commit on top and send it up, but due to that older bugfix commit, trying to rebase creates a conflict.

What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Can you reset the commit, stash it, switch to the correct `HEAD` and apply from stash without errors?

Comment: I should mention I'm a bit new to Git :)

Comment: I looked up those terms and got it to work! Thank you!

Comment: I'll enter it as an answer as well so it's better visible, then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As stated in my comment, ) The solution would be to soft reset the commit (`git reset --soft HEAD^`), stash it with `git stash save` and then switch to the correct `HEAD` via `rebase`, `checkout` or whichever way you prefer or have to use.

After this, a simple `git stash apply` should recover your work from the stash.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebase the second branch onto master, setting the first branch as upstream:

```
git rebase --onto master bad-branch second-bug-fix
```